# How to put objects into a dictionary using Dapper in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary, dapper

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
Dictionary<string,SP> dict;
```

that contains a string and a SP object.

I would like to do the following

```
dict = conn.Query("SELECT routine_name,created,modified FROM PROCEDURES").toDictionary (
                        row => (string)row.Routine_Name,
                        row => new SP (Name=row.Routine_Name,Created=row.created,Modified=row.modified));
```

The above code is not working. How can I create a SP object with the above information. I have a constructor that takes these three parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create proper model

   ```
   public class SP {
       public string RoutineName { get; set; }
       public DateTime Created { get; set; }
       public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Map your query to model properties, select it to dictionary

   ```
   Dictionary<string, SP> dictionary = connection.Query<SP>(@"
       SELECT 
            routine_name AS RoutineName,
            created AS Created,
            modified AS Modified
       FROM PROCEDURES
   ").ToDictionary(m => m.RoutineName, m => m);
   ```

Comment: @regal It would have to have a parameterless constructor as well.